# Excel VBA Scrape Web Page

Tags: vba, excel, dom, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to scrape the following webpage

http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?flag=0&expandable=7

The *search box (which says Enter Scrip Name / Code / ID)*, is where I am having difficulty,
I am able to set the value of the box to the scrip ID **500222** by using the following code,

`IE.Document.All.Item("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$GetQuote1_smartSearch").innerText = "500222"`

However if you try entering the value **500222** in the search box manually you will get a drop down box which will be the name of the corresponding scrip. I can't however make it work via VBA. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the webpage `.onkeypress` event handler function assigned to the textbox sends HTTP request and receives a response each time you press a key. Then it shows suggested items in drop down list. You don't need to figure out how does the handler function work. Just open URL from your question e. g. in Chrome, press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open **Developer Tools** window, go to **Network** tab where all page XHRs listed, type some text into search box and you will see that new requests will be displayed. Click one of them, in **Headers** tab you can find **Request URL**:

[image: network tab]

You can reproduce such XHR as textbox onkeypress event handler does, and parse Scrip Name(s) from response, here is example VBA code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub SmartGetQuoteData()

    Dim sScripID As String
    Dim sResp As String
    Dim sAllItems As String
    Dim sFirstCode As String
    Dim oXHR As Object
    Dim oDoc As Object
    Dim oBody As Object

    ' set your code here
    sScripID = "500222"

    ' make XHR
    Set oXHR = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp")
    oXHR.Open "GET", "http://www.bseindia.com/SiteCache/90D/SmartGetQuoteData.aspx?Type=EQ&text=" & sScripID, False
    oXHR.Send
    sResp = oXHR.ResponseText
    ' convert HTML to plain text
    Set oDoc = CreateObject("htmlfile")
    oDoc.Write sResp
    Set oBody = oDoc.GetElementsByTagName("body")(0)
    sAllItems = oBody.InnerText
    ' split response and get 1st part
    sFirstCode = Split(sAllItems, "|")(0)

    ' result output
    MsgBox sAllItems ' JCT ELECTRONICS LTD|JCTEL|500222
    MsgBox sFirstCode ' JCT ELECTRONICS LTD

End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you get the link mentioned in the following line though? And what is the purpose for using it here (in plain english). thanks a ton

Comment: As I wrote above `.onkeypress` event handler function assigned to the textbox sends http request to that URL and receives a response each time you press a key. Then it shows suggested items in drop down list. You don't need to figure out how does handler function work. Just open link from your question in Chrome, press F12 (developer tools window), open Network tab with all page http requests, type some text into search box and you will see that new requests will be displayed. Click one of them, in Headers tab you can find `Request URL`.