# VBA XML V6.0 How to make it wait for page to load?

Tags: excel, xml, vba, xmlhttprequest

I have been pulling my hair out trying to find an answer for this and I cant seem to find anything useful.

Basically I am pulling from a website that loads more items on it while you are on the page. I would like my code to pull the final data after its done loading but am not sure how to make XML httprequest wait for that.

Edited:

```vb
Sub pullsomesite()
    Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP
    Dim DataObj As New MSForms.DataObject
    Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP
    Dim URL As String
    URL = "somesite"
     With httpRequest
        .Open "GET", URL, True
        .setRequestHeader "If-Modified-Since", "Sat, 1 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:02:00")
        .send
        ' ... after the .send call finishes, you can check the server's response:
    End With
    While Not httpRequest.readyState = 4            '<---------- wait
Wend
 If httpRequest.Status = 200 Then
 Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:30")
    Debug.Print httpRequest.responseText
    'continue...
End If
    'Debug.Print httpRequest.Status
    'Debug.Print httpRequest.readyState
    'Debug.Print httpRequest.statusText
    DataObj.SetText httpRequest.responseText
    DataObj.PutInClipboard

    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Activate
        .Range("A1000000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
        .PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False, NoHTMLFormatting:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

#### Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What does this mean: *a page that loads more items on it while you are on the page* ??

Comment: So when I go on this website with a browser, it will open to a header and load a section at a time. I need all of these sections though. Its a company website so unfortunately I cannot just share it to make explaining it any easier.

Comment: What do you mean by "a section at a time"? Is this automatically loaded? Or is it like an ajax/javascript dynamic load (i.e., as you scroll down the page, it loads more items)

Comment: If it's not dynamic, you probably want to check for .readyState = 4.

Comment: @DavidZemens `.readyState` is always 4 for synchronous XHR like in code above @Forbidden your website obviously uses dynamic load, you may try to find out dynamic XHR parameters, eg in Chrome I see them in developer tools (F12) on Network tab, then just employ that parameters in your code.

Comment: Try approach like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26129999/2165759), if you find dynamic XHRs then at least you can add screenshots ([like this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6h997.png)) from the browser to your question.

Comment: Okay I added a screen shot, I noticed that Request Method is set to POST instead of GET but when I changed it the output was the same.

Comment: Try using `.Open "GET", URL, False`. I'll update my answer to show you how to wait so the response doesn't contain the word "Updating" (also, you shouldn't hardcode a wait time of 30 seconds)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try waiting for the ready state and body of the response not to contain the word "Updating":

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub pullSomeSite()
    Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP
    Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP
    Dim URL As String

    URL = "SomeSite"
    With httpRequest
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send
    End With
    With httpRequest
        While Not .ReadyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        If .Status = 200 Then
            While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0    '<---------- wait again
                Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
            Wend
            Debug.Print .responseText
            'continue...
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: In this case `.ReadyState = 4` condition always returns true, so the loop will be skipped since you've set synchronous mode in third argument: `.Open "GET", URL, False`.

Comment: You want to say you updated request to be **A**synchronous :) For what? Leaving XHR synchronous renders unnecessary `.ReadyState` check.

Comment: Thank you so much for attempting, however it still pulls the page with section data saying "Updating". Im trying to figure out how to find XHR parameters like @omegastripes said.

Comment: If you can't get the parameters to work, try waiting until the response body doesn't contain the word "Updating" (regardless of section)

Comment: Where would I put in the waiting period? before Send?

Comment: I would add a new waiting loop after `If httpRequest.Status = 200`

Comment: Gah! It looks like it about to work but I still get the "Updating" output. Ill put an update of my code in OP.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

A slight modification to @paul bica's answer, which hopefully can help anyone in the future.

For me I just wanted to make 20 attempts, then give up and continue with other parts of the code.

```
Option Explicit
    
Sub pullSomeSite()
    Dim httpRequest As XMLHTTP
    Set httpRequest = New XMLHTTP
    Dim URL As String
    
    Dim count_try As Long
    count_try = 1

    URL = "SomeSite"
    With httpRequest
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
        .send
    End With
    With httpRequest
        While Not .ReadyState = 4                               '<---------- wait
            Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
        Wend
        If .Status = 200 Then
            While InStr(1, .responseText, "Updating", 0) > 0    '<---------- wait again
                If count_try < 20 Then ' Set the amount of tries before giving up
                    Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:01")
                    count_try = count_try + 1 'For each try, increase with 1
                Else
                    'If more than 20 attempts where made, jump to this part of the code to continue (not get stuck in infinity loop)
                    GoTo ContinTry
                End IF
            Wend
            Debug.Print .responseText
            'continue...
        End If
    End With

ContinTry:      
'Code to handle the error for example:
Cells(1,1).Value = "Request Failed"
End Sub
```