# ReadyState Complete stuck on ReadyState = 3

Tags: excel, vba

I have been running this code to navigate to this city-data webpage for the past couple of days and it has been working fine, but all of a sudden I now get this infinite loop around `readyState = 4` and the weird thing is that sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't.

Here is my code:

```
Dim IE as Object
Dim pageaddress as string
Dim city as string
Dim state as string

city = "Chicago"
state = "Illinois"

Set IE = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
pageaddress = "http://www.city-data.com/housing/houses-" & city & "-" & state & ".html"
IE.navigate (pageaddress)
Do
    DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
```

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32359729/vba-xml-v6-0-how-to-make-it-wait-for-page-to-load for method without IE.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, this is an issue with the webpage itself, not your code. This means that you are going to have to add a timer and refresh the page after the allotted time.

I would keep note of the average load time of that page, and pick a reasonable time that's well above that average.

In this example, we will use 10 seconds.

```
Dim IE As Object
Dim pageaddress As String
Dim city As String
Dim state As String
Dim maxLoadingTime As Single, myTimer As Single

city = "Chicago"
state = "Illinois"

Set IE = CreateObject("internetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
pageaddress = "http://www.city-data.com/housing/houses-" & city & "-" & state & ".html"
IE.navigate (pageaddress)

'Set the max time to load
maxLoadingTime = 10     '< -- # of seconds to allow page to load -- <
myTimer = Timer

Do
    DoEvents
    If Timer >= maxLoadingTime + myTimer Then
        Debug.Print Time & " Notice: Connection Error. Refreshing webpage"
        IE.stop
        IE.Refresh
    End If
Loop Until IE.readyState = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

I use:
For t = 1 To 1000: If objIE.readyState <> 4 Or objIE.Busy Then t = 1: DoEvents: Next t
To sure readyState or busy don't change.