# Is there a particular way to scrape a dynamic website?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy, mechanize

I'm trying to scrape [the following webpage](https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/corporate_act.aspx).

The search box (which says Enter Security name/Code/ID), is where I am having difficulty. I can't scrape it with *xpath*, i am using mechanize library for browser simulation, but it doesn't seems to work.

I came across this question [Excel VBA Scrape Web Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128056/excel-vba-scrape-web-page?rq=1) which is very similar to my problem but i can't figure out how to implement it using Python.

the code I tried:

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.bseindia.com/corporates/corporate_act.aspx'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.open(url)
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['ContentPlaceHolder1_SmartSearch_smartSearch'] = input("enter the company name")
response = br.submit()
```

P.S.: I am a newbie in web-scraping and i want to know the solution for a college project so your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Check the Networking tab in your Developer Tool - Whenever you type, the search field does a request to https://api.bseindia.com/BseIndiaAPI/api/PeerSmartSearch/w?Type=EQ&text=foobar. you can simply scrape that endpoint directly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) framework. I think it's one of the more advanced, including instruments to simulate interacting with the site.